# Fatal error: Call to undefined function client_data() in /home/content/09/11761709/html/student/includes/menu.php on line 18

Tags: php

Fatal error occurs when user clicks on the upload new item button it throws the following message:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function client_data() in /home/content/09/11761709/html/student/includes/menu.php on line 18

the codes used on both pages are: Menu.php and upload.item.php

** codes for upload.item.php**

```
<div id="content">
    <!--Top menu-->
    <?php include('../includes/menu.php'); ?>
    <!--End menu-->

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="space_top"></div>
    <!--Sidebar-->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <?php include('../customers/sidebar.php'); ?>
    </div>
    <!--End Sidebar-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea#id1",
            theme: "modern",
            width: 550,
            height: 150,
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak        spellchecker",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media    nonbreaking",
                "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
            ],
            content_css: "css/content.css",
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter    alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link image | print preview media fullpage |  forecolor backcolor emoticons",
            style_formats: [
                {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                {title: 'Table styles'},
                {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
            ]
        });
    </script>
    <div id="incontent">
        <?php
        $select_news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news where id='" . $_GET['nid'] . "' and status =  '1'");
        while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($select_news)) {
            $title = $arr['title'];
            $text = $arr['content'];
        }
        ?>
        <div class="uih-widget ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top box_shadow  full_el left"><?php echo titles_upload_item; ?></div>
        <div class="co_box ui-corner-bottom full_el left" style="min-height:500px">
            <form  id="fileupload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"   style="width:500px">
                <input type="hidden" name="author" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
                <?php echo $mes; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="t10"></div>
                <table style="width:100%;border:0px;" cellspacing="10" class="pro_form">

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo titles_upload_title; ?></td><td class="reg_form_td"><input type="text"  name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" autocomplete="off"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo titles_upload_category; ?></td>
                        <td><select style="width:150px" type="select" name="cat_name"  onChange="getCat('../includes/find.subcat.php?cat_name=' + this.value)">
                                <option><?php echo titles_upload_scategory; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                $sel_cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
                                while ($cat_data = mysql_fetch_array($sel_cat)) {
                                    $cat_name = $cat_data['name'];
                                    $cat_id = $cat_data['id'];
                                    echo '<option value="' . $cat_id . '">' . $cat_name . '</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo titles_upload_subcategory; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="subcategory">
                                <select style="width:150px" type="select" name="scat_name">
                                    <option value="0"><?php echo titles_upload_selsubcategory; ?></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><?php echo titles_upload_desc; ?></td><td><textarea id="id1"  type="textarea" name="descr"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo titles_upload_thumb; ?></td><td><input type="file" name="thumb" value="">  <span> (JPEG or PNG 80x80px Thumbnail)</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo titles_upload_prev; ?></td><td><input type="file" name="prv" value="">   <span> (590x300 JPEG)</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo titles_upload_files; ?>(zip)</td><td><input type="file" name="zip"   value=""><span>ZIP - All your item files</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo titles_upload_scr; ?></td><td><input type="file" name="scr[]" multiple>    <span>Select multiple screenshots</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo titles_upload_demo; ?></td><td class="reg_form_td"><input type="text" name="demo" value="<?php echo $demo; ?>" autocomplete="off"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><?php echo titles_upload_mes; ?></td><td class="reg_form_td"><textarea  style="min-height:100px" type="textarea" name="rev_mes"><?php echo $msg_rev; ?></textarea>     </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td><td><input type="submit" name="add" class="menu uih-widget pointer ui-state-default ui-corner-all pl15 pr15" value="Upload"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
                var xmlhttp = false;
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    try {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        try {
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch (e1) {
                            xmlhttp = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return xmlhttp;
            }
            function getCat(strURL) {
                var req = getXMLHTTP();
                if (req) {
                    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (req.readyState == 4) {
                            // only if "OK"
                            if (req.status == 200) {
                                text = document.getElementById('subcategory').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                                //alert(text);                      
                            } else {
                                alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                    req.send(null);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**menu.php**

```
<div id="nx_menu" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { ?>
        <a class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'index' ? 'active' : ''); ?>" href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/customers/"><?php echo general_dash; ?></a>
        <a class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'profile' ? 'active' : ''); ?>" href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/customers/profile.php"><?php echo general_profile; ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/customers/settings.php" class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'settings' ? 'active' : ''); ?>"><?php echo general_settings; ?></a>
        <?php if (client_data($user_id, 'author') == 1) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/<?php echo client_data($user_id, 'username'); ?>-portfolio/<?php echo $user_id; ?>" class="menu optim ui-state-default left p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'user.profile' ? 'active' : ''); ?>"><?php echo general_portfolio; ?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/customers/earnings.php" class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'earnings' ? 'active' : ''); ?>"><?php echo general_earnings; ?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/customers/withdraw.php" class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'withdraw' ? 'active' : ''); ?>"><?php echo general_withdraw; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <form id="form" action="<?php echo ROOT_URL . '/list.items.php'; ?>" method="post">
            <a class="menu optim ui-state-default right p10 r10" href="#" onclick="sendForm()"><?php echo general_search; ?></a>
            <input class="ui-corner-all right t5 r5" style="width:250px;color:#888;" type="text" name="search" value="">
        </form>
    <?php } else { ?>

        <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/" class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'index' ? 'active' : ''); ?>"><?php echo general_home; ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/browse-items" class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'list.items' ? 'active' : ''); ?>"><?php echo general_browse; ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/register.html" class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'register' ? 'active' : ''); ?>"><?php echo general_signup; ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>/login.html" class="menu optim ui-state-default left l5 p10 <?php echo ($active_page == 'login' ? 'active' : ''); ?>"><?php echo general_login; ?> </a>
        <form id="form" action="<?php echo ROOT_URL . '/list.items.php'; ?>" method="post">
            <a class="menu optim ui-state-default right p10 r10" href="#" onclick="sendForm()"><?php echo general_search; ?></a>
            <input class="ui-corner-all right t5 r5" style="width:250px;color:#888;" type="text" name="search" value="">
        </form>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<script>
    function sendForm() {
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thats lot of codes.are you sure you cant simplify or just post a code snipett for which you need help :)

Comment: The function you're trying to call is not defined. You probably mispelt the function name or  forgot to `include` / `require` the file containing the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the error.

The function you want to call doesn't exist : `client_data()`

You maybe have to create it, or `include` or `require` a file which contain it.
You called this function two time in your file.